# Setting/Getting propertiles of function objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I access properties of function objects.

Consider, how to make this example work:

```
    var foo = function(){
            print(this.value);
    };

    foo.value=20;

    foo();
```

Comment: `this` is something different. To get it working you need to use `foo.value` inside the function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var foo = function(){
  print(foo.value);
};
```

Refer the function directly, In theory you can use `arguments.callee.value` but that's deprecated and you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this for hours.